# Matplotlib secondary axis with equal aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a secondary axis to an axis with equal aspect ratio using `twinx()`, however, as can be seen in the example below, the secondary axis does not match the aspect ratio of the original.

Is there something additional that needs to be done, or is this a bug in matplotlib?

---

**Code:**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
plt.show()
```

**Output figure:**

[image: matplotlib output]

Comment: Does it work with out `box-forced`?

Comment: Without `box-forced` the plot areas appear to be the same size, but if I plot into the second axis and resize the window it's clear the aspect ratio is changing

Comment: Interestingly, the above code sample works correctly if I create `ax1` using `host_subplot` imported from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1` instead of `fig.add_subplot`. However, in my actual code I use the object-oriented API so I don't think I can use `host_subplot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the host axis with `host_subplot` like in the [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#parasiteaxes) on parasitic axes instead of `fig.add_subplot` appears to resolve the issue. The plots now occupy the same space and have equal aspect ratios.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = host_subplot(111, adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
plt.show()
```

---

I was able to achieve the same as above with the object-oriented API used in my actual program by creating the host axis with `SubplotHost`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.parasite_axes import SubplotHost

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

fig = Figure()
ax1 = SubplotHost(fig, 111, adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
fig.add_subplot(ax1)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
canvas.show()

app.exec_()
```